# Go to XY function in GeoNode?

Tags: geoserver, coordinates, geoexplorer, geonode

My team is building a web GIS portal using GeoNode. We're trying to add a "go to XY" function or widget into MapLoom or GeoExplorer, so users can enter coordinates and pan/zoom to that location on map.

Does anyone know particular script, tool, or API to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

So, I've not worked with this before, but from the [GeoNode documentation](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/devel/devel_core/coremodules.html#geoexplorer) , they describe that GeoExplorer is basically the stock out-of-the--box implementation of the OpenGEO SDK suite:

> The GeoExplorer app is based on GeoExt, OpenLayers and ExtJS.
>   GeoExplorer is the reference implementation of the OpenGeo Suite SDK
>   which is based on GXP. GeoNode treats GeoExplorer as an external
>   module that is used out of the box in GeoNode, but it is possible for
>   you to create your own Suite SDK app and integrate it with GeoNode.

So I think that you can use the OpenGeo Suite Boundless SDK as your API for creating a plugin that does what you want. Here is documentation on creating plugins with the Boundless SDK:
[Creating application plugins](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/gxp/plugin/index.html)

Again, this is not a complete answer, but hopefully would give you some place to start investigating.

Comment: So, one other thought. It looks like it should be relatively easy to add the google geocoder tool as a plugin:http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/webapps/gxp/viewer/geocoder.htmlhttps://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple