# Customizing Geonode (Geoexplorer) Query Menu

Tags: query, geonode

I am trying to customize query result menu of Geonode. (Layer->Edit Layer->Query)

For example, I want to export query results in a specific format or create a new layer from selected features from right click menu.
I searched some but cannot find required files and it seems time consuming.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geoexplorer is a [module of geonode](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/devel/devel_core/index.html#dev-core) so you will need to understand how django works and how geoexplorer works which can be done with the [geoexplorer SDK](http://suite.opengeo.org/ee/docs/4.5/webapps/sdk.html) and by using the [geonode geoexplorer debugger](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/devel/devel_debug/geoexplorer.html) you can reverse engineer how it comes together within the geonode project.   This question was also asked in a different form over here [Go to XY function in GeoNode?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212665/go-to-xy-function-in-geonode)

The amount of time it takes to figure this all out is dependant on where you are on the learning curve and there several moving parts (django, Ext, GeoExt, JS) there is not a single doc or tutorial on how to do it but if you combine the above links you should be able to figure out how to do it.